# XSL : Sorting by attribute value when there there are several elements with similar tag names

Tags: xslt, sorting

This is a sample of the XML file :

```
<Nodes version="1">
<Node name="root">
    <Node name="message 3">
        <Prp name="date" type="D" value="41019.2289042593"/>
        <Prp name="priority" type="I" value="300"/>
        <Prp name="child index" type="I" value="-1"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="message 2">
        <Prp name="date" type="D" value="41019.2288970833"/>
        <Prp name="priority" type="I" value="300"/>
        <Prp name="child index" type="I" value="-1"/>
    </Node>
    <Node name="message 1">
        <Prp name="date" type="D" value="41019.2288965625"/>
        <Prp name="priority" type="I" value="300"/>
        <Prp name="child index" type="I" value="-1"/>
    </Node>
   </Node>
</Nodes>
```

I have to sort the "messagex" nodes according to the date (i.e the "value" attribute in   Prp name="date" type="D" value="41019.2288970833"/> field)

Im not able to find the solution as the tags have the same name and so do the attributes. Can you please guide me doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/Nodes/Node[@name='root']/Node">
    <xsl:sort select="Prp[@name='date' and @type='D']/@value"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```